# Unknown column in field list generating from fixture file

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I've created a fixture file to test an element that I've created using [Dna Design's Silverstripe Elemental package](https://github.com/dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental) and Silverstripe seems to insist that the `has_many` relationship `'Elements'` in `ElementalArea` doesn't exist.

```
SilverStripe\ORM\Connect\DatabaseException: Couldn't run query:

INSERT INTO "ElementalArea"
 ("Elements")
 VALUES
 (?)

Unknown column 'Elements' in 'field list'
```

I have the fixture file:

```
---
MyElement:
    my-element:
        ...

ElementalArea:
    elemental-area:
        Elements: =>MyElement.my-element
```

I've tried running `sake /dev/build "flush=all"` and clearing `/tmp/sivlerstripe-cache...` with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Silverstripe 4 the Elemental module is namespaced. In our fixture yml file we must provide the full namespaced path for `ElementalArea`.

Also, on a has many relationship we can set the relationship on the has one side (the Element):

```
DNADesign\Elemental\Models\ElementalArea:
  elemental-area:
    Title: 'Area 1'

DNADesign\Elemental\Tests\Src\TestPage:
  page1:
    Title: 'Page 1'
    URLSegment: 'test-page'
    ElementalAreaID: =>DNADesign\Elemental\Models\ElementalArea.elemental-area

MyElement:
  my-element:
    Title: 'Element 1'
    ParentID: =>DNADesign\Elemental\Models\ElementalArea.elemental-area
```